# How can I determine what hosting provider hosts a site?

Tags: web-hosting

Is there a service that will identify where a site is hosted (presumably by IP)?

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this looks more like a ServerFault-type question?

Comment: David: You're prly right. I'll post it there. This question came from my Q#860597 which was programming related.

Comment: Can we also determine what is the type of hosting for that website, like Linux/Windows/VPS hosting?

Comment: you can use siteprice.org api, check http://www.siteprice.org/api/

Comment: Usually, so many websites are now using proxy DNS like CloudFlare to hide their hosting server information. So, sometime it becomes difficult to find out a real hosting provider. You can try out www.Mydns.is website, it  helps you to find out who is the hosting provider behind proxy for any website.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Who-hosts](http://who-hosts.com/thedomain.com) is an online free service that can tell you which is the company that hosts the provided URL, and doesn't require registration.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the useful answer! Do you know if it possible to track the case in the reverse direction? (i.e. I know the hosting and I'd like to know which web-sites hosted there)

Answer (score 3):

tracert www.sitename.com

is probably your best bet.  The last entry or two should give you your best hint.  Otherwise, the whois entry may be a good indicator as well, especially if they are using a hosting provider for DNS.

EDIT:
Its traceroute not tracert on linux machines.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a whois search on the IP.

[http://samspade.org/whois/](http://samspade.org/whois/69.59.196.211) is a free utility for telling you who owns an IP address or domain name.  If this is a server farm hosting multiple servers, then it will likely be registered to the hosting company.

Comment: Thx. Looks like the nameserver entries reported might be a better indicator.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what the question asked for, but you might find it useful to know that [Netcraft](http://uptime.netcraft.com/) provides some pretty neat information about the uptime, web-server software, and ISP used to host websites as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Domaintools](http://whois.domaintools.com/stackoverflow.com) can usually give you some pretty good information, under the "Server Data" and using the "Reverse IP" tool (though you have to pay to get full results from that one).

Answer (score 1):

http://whois.domaintools.com/websitename.com

just put the website name in instead of websitename.com.